# Show that $\operatorname{Log}\left ( 1+\frac{1}{z} \right )=\operatorname{Log}(z+1)-\operatorname{Log}(z)$

Tags: complex-analysis, logarithms

It is well-known that whenever $a,b$ are non-zero complex numbers, then $\operatorname{Log}(a/b)=\operatorname{Log}(a)-\operatorname{Log}(b)+2\pi i k$ for some integer $k$. Here $\operatorname{Log}$ denotes the principal logarithm. I read somewhere without explanation that
$$
\operatorname{Log}\left ( 1+\frac{1}{z} \right )=\operatorname{Log}(z+1)-\operatorname{Log}(z)\tag{*}
$$
for all $z\in \mathbb{C}\setminus (-\infty,0]$. Is this valid in general? If so, why? I checked it myself to insert some values of $z$ in $\mathbb{C}\setminus (-\infty,0]$ and compare on both sides, and they look good. However, I can't seem to prove it in general, or that $k$ should be $0$ in that case (where $a=z+1$ and $b=z$).

**Update**: I have tried a slightly different way, though I might err:
Write $x=a+ib$, then
$$
\frac{z+1}{z}=1+\frac{a}{a^2+b^2}+i\frac{-b}{a^2+b^2}.\tag{**}
$$
If $a>0$, (*) is valid, as equality holds whenever $\Re z+1,\Re z>0$.

- If $a=0$, then (**) is reduced to $1-i/b$, so $\operatorname{Log}(\frac{z+1}{z})=\ln|1-i/b|+\arctan(-1/b)$, while $\operatorname{Log}(z+1)-\operatorname{Log}(z)=\ln|1-i/b|+\arctan(b)-\operatorname{Arg}(ib)$.
- $\qquad$ If $b>0$, then the latter would be equal to $\ln|1-i/b|+\arctan(b)-\pi/2$.
- $\qquad$ For $b<0$, we would instead get $\ln|1-i/b|+\arctan(b)+\pi/2$.

In both cases, I suspect that $\arctan(-1/b)$ is equal to $\arctan(b)-\pi/2$ for $b>0$ and equal to $\arctan(b)+\pi/2$ for $b<0$. I checked it with Graph calculator, and left hand side and right hand side seem to coincide. How to prove it rigorously? See update 2 below.

If $a<0$, replace $a$ by $-a'$ for $a'>0$, then (*) is still valid for $a'>0$.

**Update 2**: Define $f(x)=\arctan(-1/x)-\arctan(x)$ for $x\neq 0$. Then, we see that $f'(x)=0$, so $f$ must surely be constant. But, since $f(1)=-\pi/2$, it follows that $f(x)=-\pi/2$ for all $x\neq 0$. But, this is not entirely true, as $f(x)$ is $\pi/2$ for negative $x$. Where is the flaw in my argument?

Comment: Consider the branch cuts (of all these $3$ functions).

Comment: The main point is that $1/z$ as well as $1+1/z$ do not belong to $(-\infty, 0].$ Therefore the conclusion is not valid for $1+i/z$ as was observed in Billy Ocean's answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you draw a picture, the geometry of this problem becomes immediately clear. In general, the property that makes this work is the fact that $z$ and $z+1$ will always have arguments who's difference is less than $\pi$. That is, you can't have $z$ and $z+1$ in QII and QIII at the same time, they cannot be vertical from each other. This would  fail for any non-real number, for example,

$$\text{Log}\left(\frac{z+i}{z}\right) \not= \text{Log}(z+i) - \text{Log}(z)$$

at $z=-1-\frac{1}{2}i$. Likewise, if we chose a different branch of the logarithm that wasn't on the real line, then original statement with a $1$ would now fail too. Again, a picture really makes this clear.

Comment: Nice explanation. If I follow your strategy, wouldn't $\text{Log}\left(\frac{z+1}{z}\right) = \text{Log}(z+1) - \text{Log}(z)$ be valid for all $z\in \mathbb{C}\setminus \{0\}$, or just only for all $z\in \mathbb{C}\setminus (-\infty,0]$ as my post originally claimed?

Comment: The statement would fail on $\mathbb{C}-\{0\}$, since we could pick $z = -\frac{1}{2}$ and that would place $z+1 = \frac{1}{2}$; causing an angle of $\pi$ between the two numbers.

Comment: What about $z=-2$? We would get $\frac{z+1}{z}=\frac{1}{2}$, and $\operatorname{Log}(1/2)=\ln(1/2)=-\ln(2)$, and $\operatorname{Log}(-1)-\operatorname{Log}(-2)=\ln(1)+i\pi-(\ln(2)+i\pi)=-\ln(2)$ ...

Comment: Correct, my counterexample only works because I chose a number $z$ so that $z+1$ were on opposite sides of the origin, which breaks the equality. Yes, your logarithm statement would hold for all $\mathbb{C} - [-1,0]$, but you have to delete that whole line segment, or you could still get counterexamples.

Answer (score 0):

It is not difficult to see that, in general, if $w_1,w_2 \in \mathbb{C}\setminus (-\infty,0]$ then
$\operatorname{arg} {w_1 \over w_2} = \operatorname{arg} w_1 - \operatorname{arg} w_2 + 2k \pi$, where $k \in \{-1,0,+1\}$. So, the goal here is to show that $k=0$.

Split the analysis into three cases depending on the sign of $\operatorname{im} z$. Let $\operatorname{arg}w$ denote the angle of $w$ in $(-\pi,\pi)$.

Suppose $\operatorname{im} z > 0$, then $0< \operatorname{arg} (1+z) < \operatorname{arg} z < \pi$ and hence
$\operatorname{arg} (1+z) - \operatorname{arg} z \in (-\pi,0]$.
Note that ${1+z \over z} = {\bar{z} + |z|^2 \over |z|^2}$, from which we see that $\operatorname{arg} {1+z \over z} \in (-\pi,0]$, and so $k=0$.

The other cases, $\operatorname{im} z = 0$ and $\operatorname{im} z <0 $ are similar.

Comment: Could you please check if my understanding is correct? If $\Im z=0$, then $\operatorname{arg}(1+z)-\operatorname{arg}z=0$, still within $(-\pi,\pi)$. If $\Im z<0$, then $-\pi <\operatorname{arg} z<\operatorname{arg}(1+z)<0$, then $0<\operatorname{arg}(1+z)-\operatorname{arg} z<\pi$, again within $(-\pi,\pi)$. Both cases imply that $\operatorname{arg} \frac{1+z}{z}=\operatorname{arg}(1+z)-\operatorname{arg} z$ for all $\Im z\leq 0$, and hence, including your case, for all $z\in \mathbb{C}\setminus (-\infty,0]$.

Comment: @Mr.MathDoctor I elaborated the case $\operatorname{im} z > 0$ a little more, I omitted an important point last night. The point is to show that $k=0$ (see above) in all cases.